# Как подключить файл <d2d1.h> в программе на C

Tags: c, windows

Я использую gcc и vscode. Я написал #include<d2d1.h> и во время компиляции появляется ошибка d2d1.h: No such file or directory. Я понимаю, что этого файла нет на на компьютере, как мне скачать, подключить это файл? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<d2d1.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нужно установить Windows SDK

Comment: Не подскажите как это можно сделать? Я пробовал, у меня не получилось.

Comment: `gcc` обычно выступает, как компилятор Си. С помощью `g++` обычно компилируется код на C++. Попробуйте `g++ -o main.exe main.c`.

Comment: Скорее всего, `d2d1.h` идёт в базовой поставке Windows, т. к. инструкций по его загрузке мне найти не удалось. Вы можете убедиться в этом, выполнив поиск в папке `C:/Windows/`.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле, в папке `C:/Windows/` можно найти разве что бинарник d2d1.dll. Правильный ответ дал участник [t3f](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140854/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-d2d1-h-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c/1161011#comment1973840_1140854), этот заголовочный файл поставляется с [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/) (в том числе с урезанной версией, которая входит в Visual Studio). У меня, например, он находится в папке `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include`.

И с языком С этом заголовочный файл в принципе совместим, так как в нем помимо интерфейсов C++ определены специальные макросы для вызова методов через указатель в vtable, типа такого:

```
#define ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateBitmap(This, size, srcData, pitch, bitmapProperties, bitmap) \
    ((This)->lpVtbl->CreateBitmap(This, size, srcData, pitch, bitmapProperties, bitmap))
```

Answer (score -3):

[@Андрей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/249284/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9) в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140854/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-d2d1-h-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c/1161199#comment1973895_1140854): `gcc` обычно выступает, как компилятор Си. С помощью `g++` обычно компилируется код на C++. Попробуйте:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.c
```

И в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140854/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-d2d1-h-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c/1161199#comment1973897_1140854): Скорее всего, d2d1.h идёт в базовой поставке Windows, т. к. инструкций по его загрузке найти не удалось. Можете убедиться в этом, выполнив поиск в папке C:/Windows/.